# What do glQueryCounter and GL_TIMESTAMP really measure?

Tags: opengl

My main question is, can someone confirm that `glQueryCounter` captures the `GL_TIMESTAMP` after all previous commands were executed on the GPU? So that the difference of two timestamps will roughly be equivalent to capturing `GL_ELAPSED_TIME`?

---

What I'm looking for is a way to measure timings between more than two timestamps, while ensuring that the timestamps are captured when all previously scheduled commands were executed. I know that `GL_TIME_ELAPSED` works for two points in time, but I'd need something that can be nested and used with multiple timestamps within a single frame, which is why I'd like to use `GL_TIMESTAMP`. Timestamps may be `frameStart`, `drawCertainThingsStart`, `drawCertainThingsEnd`, `frameEnd`. The spec on `GL_TIMESTAMP` confuses me, though, and I'm not sure if it does what I'm looking for.

Disjoint timer query spec: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_disjoint_timer_query.txt

---

Some information seems contradictory. For example: 
[glQueryCounter](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glQueryCounter.xhtml): "record the GL time into a query object after all previous commands have reached the GL server but have not yet necessarily executed"

The [disjoint timer query spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_timer_query.txt) on the other hand says
"The time is recorded after all previous commands on the GL client and server state and the framebuffer have been fully realized.", which sounds like it records the timestamp after previously scheduled commands were executed.
It also specifically mentions that the synchronous alternative, GetInteger64v, returns the timestamp without necessarly having executed the commands, which emphasizes that glQueryCounter is supposed to return a timestamp after previous commands were executed, contrary to what the khronos page says.

---

The spec also comes with an example:
Section "(2) This example uses QueryCounter" supposedly shows how `glQueryCounter` and `GL_TIMESTAMP` are used to measure elapsed time on the GPU. However, it seems like this example is incomplete. Two variables, `_timeStart_` and `_timeEnd_`, are never used. Instead, the example reads the value of `GL_TIMESTAMP` directly into the `_timeElapsed_` variable, which seems wrong. From my understanding, we'd need to read `GL_TIMESTAMP` into `_timeStart_` and `_timeEnd_`, and then compute `_timeElapsed_ = _timeEnd_ - _timeStart_` .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The OpenGL function documentation pages have an unfortunately large number of errors on them. This is one of them. It's even *self*-contradictory, since the text of the description contradicts the intro text.

The OpenGL *specification* is very clear on the behavior of `glQueryCounter`:

> The time is recorded after all previous commands on the GL client and server state and the framebuffer have been fully realized.

---

> The spec also comes with an example

Wrong specification. The ARB_timer_query specification is for desktop OpenGL; the EXT_disjoint_timer_query is for OpenGL ES. Don't confuse the two.

The EXT_disjoint_timer_query specification's examples seem to have been incorrectly copied from ARB_timer_query.

Comment: "The OpenGL function documentation pages have an unfortunately large number of errors on them." I've found this to be true for other Khronos documentation pages as well, such as EGL. The pages should really come with an accuracy disclaimer that refers back to the standard.

Comment: @nebel: It's really a matter of having to have multiple copies of the same information in different places. The Vulkan function documentation is built from the same AsciiDoctor sources as the Vulkan specification (the Vulkan specs are cleverly designed to work in part as reference docs), so a change in one place is a change in all of them. Anytime you have separate documentation and specifications that have to convey the same information, you will inevitably get errors.